# Does Lucene support Faceted Search with Multiple Field Values

Tags: lucene, field, faceted-search

I am reading this article from http://www.devatwork.nl/index.php/articles/lucenenet/faceted-search-and-drill-down-lucenenet/

The author did not say whether Lucene support storing multiple values in each field.

To follow the example in the article, a book may have multiple genres and multiple authors.

Is it possible to store more than one genres in the genre field?

Is it also possible to perform searches using multiple genres or multiple authors?  The result should return a document if matching one or more of the query genres and matching one or more of the authors.

Thanks,

Vu Dang

Answer (score 1):

Core Lucene doesn't support multi-valued faceted queries, but these extension projects do:

- [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)
- [bobo-browse](http://code.google.com/p/bobo-browse/)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a doc about faceted search

https://cwiki.apache.org/LUCENENET/simple-faceted-search.html

and its usage

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/branches/Lucene.Net_2_9_4g/test/contrib/SimpleFacetedSearch/TestSimpleFacetedSearch.cs