# lucene.net DoubleRangeFacetCounts doesn't handle multi value fields

Tags: c#, lucene.net, faceted-search

We create a price facet for a lot of our customers and generally we put sale price and list price both into the facet.

Example Items:
Hat, Sale: $5 List $11

We enter both of those into the document as the field Price, so price contains the values 11 and 5. Usually put in that order.

If I made ranges such as 0 - 10 and 10 - 20 as double ranges and used those double ranges in a DoubleRangeFacetCounts I would expect to see that the first range had a count of 1 and the second range also had a count of 1 because with the multi value field that would be true.

But instead I would get a count of 0 for 0 - 10 and a count of 1 for 10 - 20. It seems to only be using the list price to determine the count.

But for our actual filtering where we use a numerical range filter to filter down the list in our drilldown query selecting 0 - 10 would return the hat product that we are expecting.

This missmatch of how the counting works with how the numerical range filter works is leading to facet counts that are off, usually not by a ton but still off.

I am using DoubleRangeFacetCounts like this:

`new DoubleRangeFacetCounts(rangeName("Price"), facetCollector, rangeFacets)`

Is there a way to get DoublrRangeFacetCounts to handle multi value fields? Should i be looking at a different route to handle range facets?

Currently the workaround is to no allow multi range facets but it is a feature we would like to support as generally you would want both list and sale prices in your Price facet

Comment: I don't think Lucene is designed to support faceting on a field with multiple values.  I'm pretty sure I read that somewhere.  Searching yes, faceting no.  I tried to find the place I read it but was unable to.  I did find this related SO question though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514390/does-lucene-support-faceted-search-with-multiple-field-values

Comment: Regular facetted search (FastTaxonomyFacetCounts) works on multi value fields. That works really well. But DoubleRangeFacetCounts doesn't seem to work on multi value fields.

I actually implemented a workaround where I convert the range into the label at index time and then treat it as a text facet which works pretty well but it still seems odd to me that Taxonomy handles multi value which double range can't

Comment: Thanks for the insights Brandon,  I wasn't aware of that.  Pretty interesting.